# issues with tr:odd in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to write this function where it will take users input from #rc and create a checker board of that size.

It works fine when n is an even number like 8, but if n is an odd number ,like 9, every "tr:2n+1" is colored wrong. what is the reason for this ? what should I do with it? Thank you in advance!

```
function setUpCheckBoard()
{
  var n = $("#rc").val();
  var stn= Number(n)+1;
var col = new Array(stn).join('<td></td>');
   var row = new Array(stn).join('<tr>' + col + '</tr>');

 $('tbody').append(row);
  $("tr:odd td:odd").css("background-color", "black");
 $("tr:odd td:even").css("background-color", "white");
 $("tr:even td:odd").css("background-color", "white");
 $("tr:even td:even").css("background-color", "black");  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
$("tr:odd td:nth-child(2n+1)").css("background-color", "black");
$("tr:odd td:nth-child(2n)").css("background-color", "white");
$("tr:even td:nth-child(2n+1)").css("background-color", "white");
$("tr:even td:nth-child(2n)").css("background-color", "black");
```

The `:odd` and `:even` selectors don't care about the parent/child relationships of the selected elements; they select every other element ***out of all the matching elements***.

So, you take `tr:odd td` and get a bunch of `td` elements from various rows of the table. When you do the `:odd` ones of those, jQuery just counts through every other matching `td` — some of which will be in the first column, and some of which will be in the second.

Using `:nth-child(2n)` and `:nth-child(2n+1)` specifically selects elements based on where they're positioned within their parent row.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you may want the plain old **CSS** to handle it for you, like so:

```
<style type="text/css">

    /* WHITE DEFAULT COLOUR */
    table tr td {
      background-color:white;
    }

    /* BLACK OVERRIDE COLOUR */
    table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even), table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color:black;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I decided to go with css instead. haha thanks.

Comment: Glad that helped! :)